# xcode jump bar symbol representations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been using xcode's jump bar feature. It is very convenient to use but occasionally I encounter symbols in the jump bar that I do not know what it represents.

[image]

For example, I want to know what the middle symbol (i.e. the symbol before Collection actually represents), where could I find relevant information on a list of symbols used and what they actually means?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even I used to wonder what these icons meant so I just went through a lot of official Swift frameworks and classes - hope this helps,

**M - module, shown for Frameworks like UIKit, UserNotifications, CoreLocation**

[image]

**Header Files mostly but this comes up for Swift classes too**

[image]

**Class & Interface (Obj-C)**

[image]

**Structs**

[image: For Structures]

**Enums**

[image]

**Extensions**

[image]

**Methods & Functions**

[image]

**Variables, Properties & Constants**

[image]

**Overloaded methods, sometimes normal methods too**

[image]

**Protocols**

[image]

**Pragma marks**

[image]

**Macros**

[image]

**TypeDef**

[image]

**Union**

[image]

**Frameworks**

[image]

**Libraries**

[image]

**Plist files**

[image]

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Entitlements**

[image]

**Folders or groups**

[image]

**Flat files**

[image]

**Header files**

[image]

**Implementation files**

[image]

**Swift files**

[image]

**Asset catalogs**

[image]

> P.S: Used Xcode 8.1, will update more if I come across anything new.

Comment: The "M" actually stands for Module.

Comment: thank you so much for the time and effort you put into the answer! this is far more than what I have ever expected! strange that apple did not provide any documentation at all for what the symbols actually represent.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Yes you are right Apple should have described these icons and what they mean. I will keep on adding what all mysterious icons I discover on Xcode :P

Answer (score 3):

You will encounter these types of symbols in the jump bar when you jump in for iOS native types like String,Int,firstIndex etc.
In the above example collections are used for data storage. Swift provides three primary collection types, known as arrays, sets, and dictionaries, for storing collections of values. Here in the example above you have jumped in for countable range which comes under collections in swift module.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. If possible, could you please tell me where I can find a list that explain what each symbol means?

Comment: Sorry but I believe there isn't any list that will explain each symbol. Either you have to use the apple developer site or if you want to see the complete list click on the last item on the jump bar (here countable range) then you can see a drop down list showing all the symbols inside that collection and clicking on a particular symbol you could get its explanation or usage